# Airconsole Code: navigator.vibrate

Tags: javascript, airconsole

I was looking at the airconsole javascript file and found a piece of code and I don't know what it describe.
Can anyone please let me know.

```
navigator.vibrate = (navigator.vibrate ||
                     navigator.webkitVibrate ||
                     navigator.mozVibrate ||
                     navigator.msVibrate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line makes the function call to vibrate the device browser-independent.

The `||` means `or` in JavaScript. The code after `||` will only be executed if the code before the `||` returns false (This is called short-circuit evaluation). So if the general `vibrate` function does not exist, it will try the WebKit-specific vibration function (for Safari and other WebKit-based browsers). If that does not exist either, the Firefox specific function, and if that won't work, the Microsoft (Internet Explorer) specific function.

See also the headline *"Browser Support and Detection"* in this [tutorial on how to use the HTML5 vibration API.](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-vibration-api/)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to use vibration that works on every browser. Every browser has a different way to use vibration (because it's probably not yet included in the standard.

The developer saves the one that works to `navigator.vibrate` and uses this one for his code. This way he doesn't have to check every time he want to use vibrate which implementation he needs to use.